# Excel VBA IE Press search button

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to program to "push" a "SEARCH" button on a webpage with VBA excel, but unfortunately all search from google.com & stackoverflow.com could not solve the problem.

My following VBA code until now:

```
Sub DownloadHomepage()
Dim eRow As Long
Dim ele As Object
Set sht = Sheets("RawData")
RowCount = 1

eRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Text = Sheet2.Cells(2, 3)

 With objIE
.Visible = True 'Hvis hjemmesiden skal fremkomme synligt - ej = False
.navigate "https://infra.soliditet.com/solsite-1.0/crWelcome.do"
'Viser først hjemmesiden når den er færdig med at loade

Do While .Busy Or _
.readyState <> 4 
DoEvents
Loop

Set what = .document.getElementsByName("standardCompanySearchForm.keyData")

what.Item(0).Value = Text

.document.getElementById("sumbit").Click  '(HERE IS THE PROBLEM-LINE THAT DOSNT WORK!)
```

The code from url when inspect the "SEARCH" button:

```
**<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="doSearch( true );" class="btn_style2" style="width: 52px;">**
```

---

The "reset" buttom left to "Search" button have following url code:

```
<input id="reset" type="button" class="btn_style2" onclick="clearFields();" value="Clear" style="width: 52px;">
```

Here I figure out how to use this button

```
.document.getElementById("reset").Click
```

but this way dosnt work for the search button

can someone please help me?

THANKS! :)

Comment: Assuming there is only one form, try `.document.forms(0).submit`

Comment: `.document.getElementById("sumbit").Click` - I think that's your problem (typo)

Comment: Any suggestions @Tim Williams?

Comment: Beyond fixing the typo "sumbit" ?  Did you try that already ?

Comment: .document.forms(0).submit That works! :) THANKS! @Portland     
  
- But the next button "Show report" I have the same issue:    

The code from url when inspect for the "Show Report"
**<input type="submit" value="Show report" onclick="selectReport();" class="btn_style2 show_button">**   

Any suggestions? (Thanks! :) )